# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable while opening chrome browser using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open and close a chrome browser using python-selenium.webdriver, but i am getting below error, i am using ubuntu system.

I have downloaded chrome browser driver and provided same path in code
I am getting below error:

> File "/home/rupesh/PycharmProjects/Selenium/selenium package/test1.py", line 3, in 
>       driver = chrome ('/home/rupesh/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

code is below :

```
from selenium.webdriver import chrome

driver = chrome ('/home/rupesh/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')

driver.close()
```

Comment: `chrome` is a submodule within Selenium; it is not a callable function.

Answer (score 1):

The driver object begins with an uppercase `Chrome` :

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

driver = Chrome('/home/rupesh/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
```

Comment: But if i am running the same program again, i am getting below error

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rupesh/PycharmProjects/Selenium/selenium package/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = Chrome ('/home/rupesh/Downloads/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')
  File "/home/rupesh/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
 File "/home/rupesh/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)

Comment: maybe use `driver.quit()` instead of `driver.close()` to close everything properly ?

Comment: Done!!! the error was chrome chrome driver 78 and i was using chrome 69, so compatibility issue, hence i upgraded to chrome 78, now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Root cause- 1) The driver object begins was started with lowercase "chrome"
            2) chrome web driver and chrome versions were different